# Listable built-in functions - Why are they so fast on numerical vectors?

Tags: implementation-details, system-performance, function-comparison

Consider the following small example, where I calculate `Exp` on a large vector by employing the *listability* which many mathematical built-in functions have:

```
data = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
RepeatedTiming[Exp[data];]
(* {0.0115, Null} *)
```

The list is packed but even unpacking it still has a good performance (it's most likely re-packed)

```
data2 = Developer`FromPackedArray[data];
RepeatedTiming[Exp[data2];]
(* {0.0705, Null} *)
```

As soon as we append a non-numerical element or a number of a different type, the performance drops drastically

```
data3 = Append[data, 1];
RepeatedTiming[Exp[data3];]
(* {3.11, Null} *)
```

Now, I'm wondering if I missed something in the documentation or if there is a place, where it is explained how exactly these calls are made so performant. Specifically, I want to know

1. Does such a call use vectorization, is it parallelized or does it just call fast, but sequential code?
2. How does this compare to `Compile` with `Parallelization` turned on?

Comment: This is just a guess, but Mathematica uses Intel's MKL, and MKL contains vectorized, parallelized, optimized functions for `Exp` and friends [https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-vm-mathematical-functions] - so my guess would be Mathematica uses MKL functions for this. I'd also guess that the MKL vector math functions beat the average C compiler - otherwise, why would C programmers use the (proprietary) MKL, for what is basically a one-liner in C.

Comment: @NikiEstner Yes, this is also my guess and I'm sure I already told this to some people here without knowing it for sure. Now I wonder if it is stated somewhere in the docs. One thing is sure, there are functions like `LogGamma` that don't perform so well which would support the MKL idea if these functions are not covered there.

Comment: `Exp[data2]` takes about as long as ``Exp[Developer`ToPackedArray@data2]``.  `data3` cannot be repacked.  What I would suggest is that `Exp[data2]` somehow takes advantage of the MKL without actually performing the `ToPackedArray` operation, since the result comes back unpacked.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good catch. Actually, I had `On["Packing"]` and I should have got a warning if it unpacks the result of `Exp[data2]` again. I will use ltrace/dtrace to see if I can extract the MKL library access on the Math Kernel process when I'm home tonight.

Comment: From: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/39353 The kernel uses highly optimized multithreaded libraries such as Intel MKL and IPP, which are tuned for optimal performance and take advantage of advanced CPU features when available. This is important for vectorized machine arithmetic and numerical linear algebra (BLAS, …) routines, which are fundamental building blocks for many computational tasks." I wonder if further details can be found. Also: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6428/ClearSpeed_WTC06_final.ppt?file_id=5915

Comment: @Moo Please go ahead and turn your comment into an answer. Especially the first link is the confirmation that wasn't able to find in the documentation center.

Comment: Re Q.1: You're not asking why the MKL is so fast, right?  Re Q.2: You're looking for documentation that listability/parallelization in the WVM interferes with the vectorization tricks of the MKL (which is my guess why `Compile` is slower)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Q1: No. I know the MKL and I knew Mma is using it but I wanted a decent reference that the *vectorized versions of numerical functions* are indeed used. Q2: The runtime of parallel compiled code is slower but similar. I wanted to make sure I understood correctly, that `Exp[list]` uses vectorized operations while `funC[list]` uses separate threads (and not vector processing units). I'm usually not that pettifogging but I needed a somewhat official reference.

Comment: FYI running a process monitor I can see that `Exp[data]` is calling the Intel IPP function [`ippsExp_64f_A53`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-exp-1) with (on my machine) vectors of length 125000 (a total of 80 calls spread over 4 threads).

Comment: @SimonWoods You are correct. I tried to find exactly this yesterday and fiddled for an hour with `strace` and `ltrace` without success. This morning, with fresh energy and your comment, I used `perf` (on Linux here) and there I saw exactly the same. Thanks so much for your investigation. I was really down last night when I couldn't find any traces of any of the Intel libraries.

Answer (score 10):

I'm collecting what we have found out and I'm concentrating for the moment on the call `Exp[data]` where `data` is a vector of reals in machine precision. For this, the following two statements seem to apply in Mathematica 11.3 with a modern CPU:

1. Single instruction, multiple data (SIMD) instructions are used provided by the MMX technology and Streaming SIMD Extensions
2. Mathematica employs the [Intel Integrated Performance Primitives](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference) library under the hood. For the `Exp` case, the function [ippsExp_64fc_A53](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-exp-1) is called.

Using a slightly more complex example, like

```
Exp[x]*Log[x + 1.0]
```

shows that all parts of the expression are relaid to the IPP libraries

- libippvm.so (ippsLn_64f_A53)
- libippvm.so (ippsExp_64f_A53)
- libipps.so (ippsAddC_64f)
- libippvm.so (ippsMul_64f_A53)

Evidently, not all functions are available in the IPP and then it gets complicated and there is no general rule. For instance

```
data = RandomReal[1, 10^7];
Do[LogGamma[data], {200}] // AbsoluteTiming
Do[Log[Gamma[data]], {200}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {10.2816, Null} *)
(* {9.09973, Null} *)
```

It appears that the `Gamma` function is implemented in `libWolframEngine` and `LogGamma` is a combination of Wolfram code for `Gamma` and the log function from `libm` on my machine. The second call however uses IPP for the logarithm and appears to be a bit faster here.

As soon as we set a specific precision, different implementations are used that partly employ the [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/). As expected, the runtime drops significantly several orders of magnitude (100x - 1000x).

My second question was, how this relates to compiled code. I want to differentiate two cases

1. A parallelized compiled function that gets one number and is made listable.
2. A compiled function that receives a tensor of numbers and calls `Exp[list]` in its body

In the first case, it appears that no vectorization is used at all. The parallelism comes from spawning multiple threads. The second case is more interesting. My tests showed that even in the compiled code, IPP library functions are called. For simple cases, however, the runtime of the compiled code cannot compete with simply using high-level calls.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one that I could find in [*Wolfram Support*](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/39353):

"The kernel uses highly optimized multithreaded libraries such as Intel MKL and IPP, which are tuned for optimal performance and take advantage of advanced CPU features when available. This is important for vectorized machine arithmetic and numerical linear algebra (BLAS, …) routines, which are fundamental building blocks for many computational tasks."

I wonder if further details can be found in the Wolfram documentation.

Comment: You might mention that the WTC PPT is a 2006 presentation by the vendor of [a defunct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearSpeed).

Comment: @MichaelE2: Good point - in fact, that is enough to remove the link! Thanks