# Speed up Do loops in MMA 13.0

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, numerics

How to speed up **Do** loop in MMA 13.

We consider the following Benchmark test (*4 kernels, i7, win10*):

In MMA 13:

```
s = 5000;
Hmm = ConstantArray[0, {s, s}];

Do[Do[Hmm[[r, c]] = 1/(r + c - 1), {r, s}], {c, s}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes **36.8516356 seconds.**

But in ***Matlab 2021b***

```
s = 5000;
H = zeros(s,s);

tic 
for c = 1:s
    for r = 1:s
        H(r,c) = 1/(r+c-1);
    end
end
toc
```

It only takes **0.114233 seconds......**

Nearly **360 times** slower than Matlab 2021b...

**Update:**

1.)
If we use "**Table**"

```
s = 5000;
Hmm = ConstantArray[0, {s, s}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 Table[Table[Hmm[[r, c]] = 1/(r + c - 1), {r, 1, s}], {c, 1, s}]]
```

It takes **36.6726 seconds...**

2.)
If we use "**For**"

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 For[c = 1, c <= s, c++, 
  For[r = 1, r <= s, r++, Hmm[[r, c]] = 1/(r + c - 1)]]]
```

It takes **46.7529 seconds...**

3.) Test results from Matlab 2021b

[image]

4.) If we try "**Compile**" (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261329/54516)

```
Compile[{}, Module[{s, Hmm}, s = 5000;
     Hmm = Table[0., s, s];
     Do[Do[Hmm[[r, c]] = 1/(r + c - 1), {r, s}], {c, s}]; 
     Hmm]][]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes **1.0638 seconds...**

Nearly **10 times** slower than Matlab 2021b...

5.) If we try another "Compile" (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261329/54516)

```
cf0 = With[{s = s}, 
    Compile[{}, Table[1/(r + c - 1), {r, 1, s}, {c, 1, s}], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]][[-1]];

Hmm = cf0[]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes **0.181941 seconds...**

Nearly **2 times** slower than Matlab 2021b...

Note that, for this special case: MATLAB and Mathematica are **NOT** equally fast.

6.) Why is `tic/toc` used (@xzczd's Question)?

Because e.g. "Use a pair of tic and toc calls to report the total time required for element-by-element matrix multiplication; use another pair to report the total runtime of your program." (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html)

Please check: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html

7.) How about **julia 1.6.3**  Do loops speed

```
@time Hmm=[1. /(r+c-1) for r=1:s,c=1:s];
    #  0.107591 seconds (85.06 k allocations: 195.439 MiB, 44.46% compilation time)
```

from @xzczd: (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261329/54516):

It takes **0.107591 seconds...** @xzczd.

8.) The computational performance of the @chyanog's MMA code  (@chyanog's comments  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261329/54516)

```
s = 5000; 
 cf = With[{s = s}, 
   Compile[{{r, _Integer}}, Table[1/(r + c - 1), {c, 1, s}], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]]; 
 Hmm = cf[Range[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes **0.0717162 seconds...** @chyanog.

Nearly **1.5 times** faster than Matlab 2021b...

9.) "**ParallelTable**"

Based on the update 8.), now we test the ParallelTable :

```
cf = With[{s = s}, 
   Compile[{{r, _Integer}}, ParallelTable[1/(r + c - 1), {c, 1, s}], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]];

Hmm = cf[Range[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Then what's the first-time cost of your MATLAB program?

Comment: @xzczd in this post.

Comment: 1. Notice I'm compiling with -Ofast option of TDM-GCC, have you set the compiler properly? 2. By first-time cost I mean timing with a fresh kernel of MATLAB 3. `s=5000` is small, what's the timing of larger `s`?

Comment: @xzczd if your conclusion is "Now MATLAB and Mathematica are equally fast." please show us the run time from MATLAB in your answer! It can be  very helpful!

Comment: I don't have access to MATLAB, but I've shown the timing of uncompiled `Table` and gfortran, which should be enough for comparison.

Comment: For a fair comparison, you should include `H = zeros(s,s)` inside `tic..toc`, imo.

Comment: @MichaelE2 in such case: >> untitled
Elapsed time is 0.125228 seconds.
>> untitled
Elapsed time is 0.122755 seconds.
>> untitled
Elapsed time is 0.128294 seconds.

Comment: Another hint: `Do[Do[Hmm[[r, c]] = 1/(r + c - 1), {r, 1}], {c, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming`.  (Basically, preallocation was pointless.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's the fastest I've found:

```
foo = Divide[1., 
    Outer[Plus, Range[1., s], Range[0., s - 1]]]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.175878, Null}  *)

foo == Hmm
(*  True  *)
```

For comparison, moving `H = zeros(s,s)` inside `tic..toc`, the MATLAB timing on my machine is `0.166379`.

---

*Addendum: Notes*

The trouble with the OP's first code is that `Hmm` has to be unpacked when `1/(r+c-1)` is a rational number and not an integer. Yes, I mean integer because the preallocation was an array of integers. `Do[..]` and `Table` are still disappointingly slow even with the proper preallocation and formula.

Comment: While I'm typing! :D

Comment: @Silvia Yes, I just saw yours. :)

Comment: For Do way, I thought of pre-allocating as a `NumericArray`, but couldn't find handy way to mutate it other than C interface in WolframNumericArrayLibrary.h.

Comment: @Silvia If you use `Do[]`, then this seems a lower limit, `Do[r, {r, 5000}, {c, 5000}] // AbsoluteTiming`, which takes almost 1.8 sec. on my computer. Inside `Compile[]`, it takes only `0.1` sec.  Unless there's a trick  to speed up `Do`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 why is  "DO" loop in Matlab so much faster (nearly 360 times)? Here: for <-> Fo[]

Comment: @ABCDEMMM I could say, "Because the loop is so much slower in Mathematica," and, although a non-answer, it expresses the limit of my knowledge. :) `Do[]` is has some generality, so I would expect *some* overhead, but this seems a lot more than necessary to me at present.

Answer (score 21):

```
Hmm = 
   With[{s = s}, 
     Compile[{}, Table[1/(r + c - 1), {r, 1, s}, {c, 1, s}]]][]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.707614, Null} *)
```

If you insist on `Do`:

```
Compile[{}, Module[{s, Hmm},
     s = 5000;
     Hmm = Table[0., s, s];
     Do[Do[Hmm[[r, c]] = 1/(r + c - 1), {r, s}], {c, s}]; Hmm](*,
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"*)][]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.9933, Null} *)
```

For comparison, `Table[Table[Hmm[[r, c]] = 1/(r + c - 1), {r, 1, s}], {c, 1, s}];` takes `37` seconds on my laptop.

---

Since the speed of MATLAB is suspiciously fast, I tested the following sample with gfortran (TDM-GCC-10.3.0-2, with compile option -Ofast):

```fortran
program tst
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
implicit none
integer,parameter::s=5000
integer::r,c
real(real64)::hmn(s,s)
do r=1,s
    do c=1, s
        hmn(r,c)=1._real64/(r + c - 1)
    end do 
end do
print *, hmn(s,s)
end program
```

The compilation timing is `0.2152324` second and execution timing is `0.1160831` second. <strike>I know little about MATLAB, but perhaps the `tic`/`toc` of MATLAB doesn't count the compilation timing.</strike> I've also tested with julia 1.6.3:

```julia
@time (s=5000; Hmm=[1. /(r+c-1) for r=1:s,c=1:s];)
#  0.107591 seconds (85.06 k allocations: 195.439 MiB, 44.46% compilation time)
```

Anyway, if we take away the compilation timing and extract the `LibraryFunction[…]` as mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132130/why-is-compilationtarget-c-slower-than-directly-writing-with-c#comment357213_132130):

```
cf0 = With[{s = s}, 
    Compile[{}, Table[1/(r + c - 1), {r, 1, s}, {c, 1, s}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]][[-1]];

Hmm = cf0[]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0954907, Null} *)
```

Now MATLAB and *Mathematica* are equally fast. Still, my compiler is TDM-GCC-10.3.0-2, with compile option -Ofast.

---

Aha, `FunctionCompile` performs slightly better than fortran, if only compilation timing doesn't need to be counted!:

```
cf = 
   FunctionCompile[
    Function[Typed[s, "MachineInteger"], 
     Table[1./(r + c - 1), {r, 1, s}, {c, 1, s}]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.47833, Null} *)

cf[5000]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0772538, Null} *)
```

All the tests are done with *Mathematica 12.3.1, Windows 10*, on a laptop with i7-8565U CPU.

---

I believe `s=5000` is too small for accurate timing, so I turn to `s=15000`, the result is as follows:

fortran
compilation timing: `0.2057823`
execution timing: `0.7179657`

julia (Timing given by `@time` of julia oscillates quite a bit, the following is an average of 10 measurements. )
`0.7945998`

`cf` (`FunctionCompile` of *Mathematica*)
`0.643739`

Comment: Perhaps OP could print UNIX time before and after the `tic`/`toc` and subtract to see if `tic`/`toc` does indeed ignore compile time or not.

Comment: default `real` is 32bit in fortran

Comment: @I.M. Thx for pointing out. (I know little about fortran, too. ) The sample is revised, and the timing increases to `0.1160831` second now.

Comment: @xzczd
matlab solver does not run in fortran... it runs in c/c++... also with MKL ....

Comment: @a I use fortran for estimating the limit of timing because fortran is famous for its speed.

Comment: @xzczd but C/C++ is also famous for its speed... e.g. Eigen (C++ library)

Comment: @a AFAIK, the traditional view is, they're almost equally fast.

Comment: @xzczd is there a good way to call  Eigen (C++ library) in MMA?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132723/discussion-between-xzczd-and-abcdemmm).

Comment: This version is a little faster. `s=15000;cf=With[{s=s},Compile[{{r,_Integer}},Table[1/(r+c-1),{c,1,s}],CompilationTarget->"C",RuntimeOptions->"Speed",RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}]];
Hmm=cf[Range[s]];//AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: @chyanog Wow, why not posting it as a separate answer?

Comment: @xzczd see the new update!

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Once again, I'm afraid this is related to your compiler. On my laptop the timing is around `0.50517`.

Comment: @xzczd if we directly run his code, it takes such time, but only run "Hmm=cf[Range[s]]" , it is very fast, see the new update!

Comment: @xzczd the Julia code might be faster as `Hmm = 1 ./ ((1:s) .+ transpose(1:s) .- 1)`

Comment: @Simon Not obvious, but it's indeed slightly faster. (This is a bit suprising to me actually, I remember the so-called devectorization is encouraged around julia v0.2! )

Comment: @xzczd how is the simple loop-performance in MMA-GPU? also very slow?

Comment: @a I don't have experience with GPU, but AFAIK `Do` loop is always not fast if not compiled.

Answer (score 19):

As other answers have suggested, a better approach here is to stick to high efficient functional way, and try to take advantage of ["vectorizable"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/187210/17) operation when possible.

For OP's question, one possible way is (time measured on a laptop with Intel i7):

```
AbsoluteTiming[hmm = Range[5000] // N // Outer[Plus, #, #] & // 1/(# - 1) &;]
(* Out[] = {0.195207, Null} *)
hmm // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(* Out[] = True *)
```

Here `Range[5000] // N` creates a [`PackedArray`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) that supports efficient storage and computing. `Outer` invokes [auto-compilation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54996/17) with internal typed-version which is also very efficient. At last `1/(# - 1) &` uses vectorized version of `Plus`, `Power`, `Times`, etc. to transform the inputted array "as a whole".

To compare, try this 1/100 size example without vectorization, yet it's slower than above code:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Range[500] // N // Outer[1/(#1 + #2 - 1) &, #, #] &;]
(* Out[] = {0.276201, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 13):

Much of the time may be spent in formatting the output, that is not shown because it is very large. Also, it may be possible to reserve space for hmm, but creating a big null matrix and redefining it does not work. This is a simple way  to improve the timing:

```
s=5000
line = Range[0, s - 1]
lineJ[j_] := (1./(# + j) & /@ line)
hmm = lineJ /@ Range[1, s] // AbsoluteTiming; (* this ; supresses output *)
hmm[[1]]
```

yields 1.28 s in my notebook (i7 on windows 11). Notice also that in lineJ[ ] the numerator is 1. (a real number), not 1 (an Integer); with 1, the matrix will be constituted of rationals and will take much longer to build (21 s), which is not the case with MatLab. A faster way is

```
rmm = (1.0/Range[#, # + s - 1]) & /@ Range[1, s] // AbsoluteTiming;
```

which gives 0.42 s.

Comment: Taking `1.0/x` to `Divide[1.0, x]` gives a 5.5x speedup on my machine. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927 for more details.

Answer (score 11):

As a general rule, avoid `Do`. In this case, `Table` is more efficient

```
Clear["Global`*"]

s = 5000;
```

The matrix initialization is part of defining the matrix with `Do` and should be included in the timing.

```
(Hmm = ConstantArray[0, {s, s}];
  Do[Do[Hmm[[r, c]] = 1/(r + c - 1), {r, s}], {c, s}]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {31.1698, Null} *)
```

Note that it is more efficient to use to use a single `Do` rather than nested `Do`

```
(Hmm2 = ConstantArray[0, {s, s}];
  Do[Hmm2[[r, c]] = 1/(r + c - 1), {r, s}, {c, s}]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {28.4179, Null} *)
```

When using `Table`, the assignment should be done only once, i.e., at the matrix level rather than the element level.

```
(Hmm3 = Table[1/(r + c - 1), {r, s}, {c, s}];) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {16.9393, Null} *)
```

Even `Array` is faster than `Do`

```
(Hmm4 = Array[1/(#1 + #2 - 1) &, {s, s}];) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {24.1783, Null} *)
```

Verifying the equivalence of the different approaches,

```
Hmm === Hmm2 === Hmm3 === Hmm4

(* True *)
```

I cannot speak to MatLab, as I do not use it (and don't have access to it).

Answer (score 10):

Matlab code is not fully optimized!!! See following code:

```
s = 5000;
tic
% for-loop version
H = zeros(s,s);
for c = 1:s
    for r = 1:s
        H(r,c) = 1/(r+c-1);
    end
end
toc

tic;
% vectorized version
c = 1:s;
r = c';
HH=1./(r+c-1);
toc

isequal(H,HH)
```

Vectorized Matlab code is much more faster (cca 25x) than simple for-loop.

```
Elapsed time is 0.168488 seconds.... for-lop
Elapsed time is 0.007221 seconds.... vectorized
```

So, in general, Matlab is in floating point numerics always significantly faster than Mathematica. Moreover, Matlab multi-threading support is much more better for majority of Matlab built-in functions.

Comment: I believe `s=5000` is too small, what if you test with `s=15000`? (See my post for timing of fortran and julia. )

Comment: Ok, let's talk only about Mathematica and Matlab. Matlab vectorized code is about 25x faster than its for-loop version. I think for benchmark purposes should be taken the vectorized version.

Comment: Once again, what if you test with `s=15000`?

Comment: Elapsed time is 1.359625 seconds.... For-loop
Elapsed time is 0.047916 seconds.... Vectorized

Comment: @xzczd can we have such performance (multi-threading) for this kind of simulation in MMA?

Comment: Then again I feel the timing of MATLAB suspicious, because the timing of fortran and julia seems to suggest the limit of `s=15000` is around 0.7 second for an average PC, and a 10x speed-up is just incredible in my eyes, but who knows. To @a : I don't think parallelization will help in this case, the communication is too expensive, have you read this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48295/1871

Comment: @xzczd I added paralleltable results, see the update!

Comment: @a `ParallelTable` cannot be compiled, see this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/1871

Comment: Vectorization is in Matlab very well supported by multi-threaded functions. But, I am sure that Matlab timing is very reliable and precise. So, this Matlab performance is definitely not any kind of artefact.

Comment: For s=20000, still relevant Matlab timing results corresponding to expexted complexity. Elapsed time is 2.526585 seconds (for-loop) 
Elapsed time is 0.100607 seconds (vectorized)

Comment: Can you add the hardware parameters of your PC to the answer? BTW, since this is no longer a pure _Mathematica_ question, I started a new question in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70531385/1551513

Comment: Ref the [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70531385/is-the-timing-of-matlab-reliable-if-yes-can-we-reproduce-the-performance-with/70531631#70531385) by xzczd, it looks like MATLAB is inadvertently "cheating" here, and the majority of the vectorisation time savings here are actually due to avoiding a cold-start on memory allocation - running this from a clear workspace shows only a 50% speed up (approx) for vectorisation. Still worth having but nowhere near the stated advantage shown here.

Comment: @Wolfie so we're dealing with some kind of expression cache here?

Comment: I am afraid that the situation is not so clear as I expected. All previous timings I performed on Cloud Matlab service Matlab OnLine (virtualized Matlab instances). On regular 8core PC (INTEL i9 CPU) is the situation different: (s = 15000)
Elapsed time is 0.477092 seconds. ... (for-loop)
Elapsed time is 0.106886 seconds. ... (vectorized)

Comment: @Pavel As noted in my answer to the linked question, I think it's just memory pre-allocation. The expression/calculation itself isn't cached, but when re-running the same command without clearing the already-assigned variables the required memory for the output array is already allocated in one of the cases, meaning this (time consuming) step can be skipped.

Comment: @Wolfie Intuitively I don't think any kind of memory pre allocation can give such speedup but I may be wrong

Comment: @Pavel The MATLAB license fee lets you leave intuition at the door and does a lot of heavy lifting to justify its cost ;)

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to precompute all quotients and then extract each row:

```
cf3 = FunctionCompile[
  Function[Typed[s, "MachineInteger"], 
    With[{vals = Divide[1.0, Range[2 s - 1]]},
      Table[vals[[k ;; k + s - 1]], {k, s}]
    ]
  ]
];

cf3[5000]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0388719, Null}
> ```

Comment: Literally translating code is indeed always a bad indeed. This is a very nice way of doing it in a very smart way, and very fast!

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, it's not the answer, just a long comment.

Considering the `Outer` version in this manner:

```
time WolframKernel <<EOF
With[{s = 15000}, 
 Table[AbsoluteTiming[
    Divide[1., Outer[Plus, Range[1., s], Range[0., s - 1]]]][[1]], 30]]
EOF
```

gives me

```
real    0m17.796s
user    0m56.334s
sys 1m18.325s
```

So the system spends more time in system calls than actually doing something.
`strace` ing shows that sys calls are `sched_yield` so we're dealing with OMP usage here. I think this should be addressed by WRI

[image]